# scala: adding a method to List?

Tags: scala

I was wondering how to go about adding a 'partitionCount' method to Lists, e.g.:
(not tested, shamelessly based on List.scala):

Do I have to create my own sub-class and an implicit type converter?

(My original attempt had a lot of problems, so here is one based on @Easy's answer):

```
class MyRichList[A](targetList: List[A]) {
  def partitionCount(p: A => Boolean): (Int, Int) = {
    var btrue = 0
    var bfalse = 0
    var these = targetList
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      if (p(these.head)) { btrue += 1 }  else { bfalse += 1 }
      these = these.tail
    }
    (btrue, bfalse)
  }
}
```

and here is a little more general version that's good for Seq[...]:

```
implicit def seqToRichSeq[T](s: Seq[T]) = new MyRichSeq(s)

class MyRichList[A](targetList: List[A]) {
  def partitionCount(p: A => Boolean): (Int, Int) = {
    var btrue = 0
    var bfalse = 0
    var these = targetList
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      if (p(these.head)) { btrue += 1 }  else { bfalse += 1 }
      these = these.tail
    }
    (btrue, bfalse)
  }
}
```

Comment: Might not need a subclass (of course, in more complicated cases...), but definitely need a[n implicit] conversion. Classes in Scala are still sealed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use implicit conversion like this:

```
implicit def listToMyRichList[T](l: List[T]) = new MyRichList(l)

class MyRichList[T](targetList: List[T]) {
    def partitionCount(p: T => Boolean): (Int, Int) = ...
}
```

and instead of `this` you need to use `targetList`. You don't need to extend `List`. In this example I create simple wrapper `MyRichList` that would be used implicitly.

You can generalize wrapper further, by defining it for `Traversable`, so that it will work for may other collection types and not only for `List`s:

```
implicit def listToMyRichTraversable[T](l: Traversable[T]) = new MyRichTraversable(l)

class MyRichTraversable[T](target: Traversable[T]) {
    def partitionCount(p: T => Boolean): (Int, Int) = ...
}
```

Also note, that implicit conversion would be used only if it's in scope. This means, that you need to `import` it (unless you are using it in the same scope where you have defined it).

Answer (score 3):

As already pointed out by *Easy Angel*, use implicit conversion:

```
implicit def listTorichList[A](input: List[A]) = new RichList(input)

class RichList[A](val source: List[A]) {

    def partitionCount(p: A => Boolean): (Int, Int) = {
        val partitions = source partition(p)
        (partitions._1.size, partitions._2.size)
    }
}
```

Also note that you can easily define `partitionCount` in terms of `partinion`. Then you can simply use:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11)
val (odd, even) = list partitionCount {_ % 2 != 0}
```

If you are curious how it works, just remove `implicit` keyword and call the `list2richList` conversion explicitly (this is what the compiler does transparently for you when `implicit` is used).

```
val (odd, even) = list2richList(list) partitionCount {_ % 2 != 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy Angel is right, but the method seems pretty useless. You have already `count` in order to get the number of "positives", and of course the number of "negatives" is `size` minus `count`.

However, to contribute something positive, here a more functional version of your original method:

```
def partitionCount[A](iter: Traversable[A], p: A => Boolean): (Int, Int) =
   iter.foldLeft ((0,0)) { ((x,y), a) => if (p(a)) (x + 1,y) else (x, y + 1)}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating the intermediate lists. In truth, I really want to add this to some "Iterable" class - not sure which though.