# How do I extend an instance of a class (e.g. a List[Int]) with some extra methods?

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [scala: adding a method to List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975754/scala-adding-a-method-to-list)

I struggle to formulate what I'm trying to do, but the code example should be pretty straightforward. If anyone knows a better way to phrase it, you are free to edit the title. :)

```
trait DiceThrow {
  list: List[Int] =>   // something like this??
  def yatzee = list.filter(_ == list.head).length >= 5
}

object Main extends App {
  val aThrow = List(4,4,4,4,4) with DiceThrow
  aThrow.yatzee  // => true    is what I want
}
```

So I want the `aThrow: List[Int]` to have some extra methods, like knowing whether it's a `yatzee` or not. This is just one example I made up where adding some extra methods to e.g. a `List` could be useful.

Is this possible somehow? Or is there another approach that's more *the scala way*? I believe it's possible with *implicit conversion*(?)(they're still pretty "magic" to me), but that seems unnecessarily dirty this use-case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *enrich (pimp) my library* pattern:

```
class DiceList(list: List[Int]) {
  def yatzee = list.filter(_ == list.head).length >= 5
}

implicit def list2DiceList(list: List[Int]) = new DiceList(list)
```

In scala 2.10 it could be simplified with [implicit classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/implicit-classes.html):

```
implicit class DiceList(list: List[Int]) {
  def yatzee = list.filter(_ == list.head).length >= 5
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
object Main extends App {
  val aThrow = List(4,4,4,4,4)
  aThrow.yatzee  // => true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty cool, but also a little "magical". Not necessarily for me, but if others were to look at my code. Isn't there an *explicit* way to do this also? (If not, shouldn't there be?)

Comment: I can also imagagine there being some unneccessary overhead for the scala compiler(?) since it has to scan through all the `implicit class`es that could extend `List[Int]` looking for the method with that particular name? (Also, autocomplete wouldn't be if any help since it thinks I'm working with an ordinary `List[Int]`). And lastly, what if there are *two* implicit classes that extends `List[Int]` - how would it choose? (given that they both had a method with the same name?)

Comment: @kornfridge Yep, there will be some overhead but I doubt if you see the difference (do you really count compilation milliseconds)? It's hard to say something about autocompletion, since it is IDE feature (e.g. IDEA is able to infer functions that implicit's bring to the table, not sure about others). Since List is sealed, I don't think you can somehow extend it without implicits.

Comment: in scala 2.10 you can also turn DiceList in a value class, which eliminates the overhead: `implicit class DiceList(list: List[Int]) extends AnyVal ...`. Concerning autocompletion, I don't know for eclipse but IntelliJ's autocompletion does find these "extension methods" ( here `yatzee` ) and even underlines them in gray so as to distinguish them from standard methods. Final point, scaladoc in scala 2.10 will also list those methods in the documentation for class on which they apply. Although in this case it won't help much as you're enriching a standard lib class rather a class of your own

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles AFAIK, no, you cannot. List is not a proper underlying type.

Comment: It would still be nice if it could be more explicit when I create the `val aThrow = List(4,4,4,4,4)`. The user will think it's a list, and nothing more, and then suddenly there's a call to `yatzee` out of nowhere? :P   But if it all happends within the same file, I guess it could pass... But what about **deligation**? Is it possible to deligate *transparently* - without having to "implement" every method that the inner class (here `List[Int]`) has?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Well I just tried it and it does work (although in my above example I forgot to make `list` a `val`). Tested in scala 2.10-RC2.

Comment: `Is it possible to deligate transparently - without having to "implement" every method that the inner class`: unfortunately scala has no built-in mecanism for "proper" delegation (by proper I mean that the wrapping class does also implement the same inteface to which it delegates). The closest that you can do out of the box (short of using compiler plugins or macros) is to use an implicit conversion from the "delagate" to the "delegatee".

Comment: Actually [SIP-15](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html) doesn't explicitly limits the Underlying type U to AnyVal. It only states that it must not be a Value Class itself. So @RegisJean-Gilles solution seems valid

Comment: Alright, thanks guys! Even though I would like there to be another (more explicit) way, this is accepted since it's (currently) the only way to do what I'm asking for. :)

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles sorry, you're right, works on 2.10.0-RC5 as well.